# Where can I find the story of Kaundinya's mountain retreat?

Tags: sangha

According to my understanding [Koṇḍañña was the first to understand the Buddha's teaching and reach enlightenment at the Deer's Park](https://www.buddha-vacana.org/sutta/samyutta/maha/sn56-011.html).  The senior monk was held in high-esteem, then he retired to the Himalayas in his last years.  Where is the story of his retirement found? I already searched the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaundinya), but it seems controversial. Was he the same one as [Vimalakoṇḍañña - born to King Bimbisāra](https://suttafriends.org/sutta/thag1-1/) (wiki makes a relationship but I am doubtful)?